# Query Optimization for finding newest entries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a currency rate database and want to select only the most recent rates by having a timestamp defining the recentness. (Selecting the most recent one per rate, not over all as they could have different timestamps)

The following query does what I want, but is super slow (>3 seconds)

```
SELECT  cR.currencyCode, cR.rate, cR.timestamp FROM currentRates cR
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(timestamp) as max, currencyCode 
       FROM currentRates 
       GROUP BY currencyCode) cR_mt 
ON (cR.timestamp = cR_mt.max AND cR.currencyCode = cR_mt.currencyCode);
```

---

The table Schema is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `currentRates` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `currencyCode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

With there being currently ~ 150k entries.

---

Could you please help me with your knowledge to improve the time of the query. I already did an index on rate and currencyCode and got down to 3 seconds (before it took ~10 seconds)

Thanks so much for your help!

L1am0

Comment: The problem is a missing index. As an aside, note that its rare for currencies to not be DECIMAL.

Comment: That's true! Changed it to DECIMAL :D

Comment: "Selecting the most recent one per rate," Your current query can return ties... When two or more records have the same max value within the group currencyCode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grouping by `currencyCode` and calculating the max `timestamp`, so your index should be `currencyCode, timestamp` in that order.

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_currentRates_CurrencyCode_Timestamp ON currentRates (currencyCode, timestamp)
```

Comment: Just for me being interested, do you have a good resource on indexes? So next time I get it myself why I should choose the one you did?

Comment: @l1am0 SO is the best resource I know.

Comment: @l1am0 you can check out https://use-the-index-luke.com/, make sure to read the one for your DMBS (mysql).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
SELECT cR.currencyCode, cR.rate, cR.timestamp
FROM currentRates cR
WHERE cR.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(cr2.timestamp)
                      FROM currentRates cR2
                      WHERE cR2.currencyCode = cR.currencyCode
                     );
```

Then you want an index on `currentRates(currencyCode, timestamp desc)`.

Comment: No clue why, but that query kills the mysql server. phpmyadmin tells me 504 and the server connection being lost.

Comment: "No clue why, but that query kills the mysql server" it's because this query is a co-related subqeury which scales very badly in MySQL on a large number of records without correct indexing.  Without correct indexing the execution runs like two nested for(each) loops meaning it loops 150K * 150K records  @l1am0

Comment: @GordonLinoff Got the one from the accepted answer: CREATE INDEX IDX_currentRates_CurrencyCode_Timestamp ON currentRates (currencyCode, timestamp DESC)

Comment: @l1am0 . . . That is the right index.  And this version isn't working.  Interesting.